# "An Object or Column Name is missing" when trying to run a dynamically generated update query from VBA to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am trying to make a tool that takes a data file that is pulled from a website and pushes that data to SQL server.

My existing structure uses VBA to navigate to the website, pull, and polish the file. Then it opens Access which imports the data to SQL Server, which has a series of VBA based reporting tools pointed to it.

I want to cut out the Access part of it and just send an update query from the VBA to the Server.

The source file is 104 columns. I have made the new tool that goes to the website, pulls the file, moves the data to the tool's workbook and transforms it.

Here is the code I put together to build the update query:

```
SQL = "Insert Into datafile(" & HVal1 & "," & HVal2 & "," & HVal3 & "," & HVal4 & "," & HVal5 & "," & HVal6 & "," & HVal7 & "," & HVal8 & "," & HVal9 & "," & HVal10 & "," & HVal11 & "," & HVal12 & "," & HVal13 & "," & HVal14 & "," & HVal15 & "," & HVal16 & "," & HVal17 & "," & HVal18 & "," & HVal19 & "," & HVal20 & "," & HVal21 & "," & HVal22 & "," & HVal23 & "," & HVal24 & "," & HVal25 & "," & HVal26 & "," & HVal27 & "," & HVal28 & "," & HVal29 & "," & HVal30 & "," & HVal31 & "," & HVal32 & "," & HVal33 & "," & HVal34 & "," & HVal35 & "," & HVal36 & "," & HVal37 & "," & HVal38 & "," & HVal39 & "," & HVal40 & "," & HVal41 & "," & HVal42 & "," & HVal43 & "," & HVal44 & "," & HVal45 & "," & HVal46 & "," & HVal47 & "," & HVal48 & "," & HVal49 & "," & HVal50 & "," & _
HVal51 & "," & HVal52 & "," & HVal53 & "," & HVal54 & "," & HVal55 & "," & HVal56 & "," & HVal57 & "," & HVal58 & "," & HVal59 & "," & HVal60 & "," & HVal61 & "," & HVal62 & "," & HVal63 & "," & HVal64 & "," & HVal65 & "," & HVal66 & "," & HVal67 & "," & HVal68 & "," & HVal69 & "," & HVal70 & "," & HVal71 & "," & HVal72 & "," & HVal73 & "," & HVal74 & "," & HVal75 & "," & HVal76 & "," & HVal77 & "," & HVal78 & "," & HVal79 & "," & HVal80 & "," & HVal81 & "," & HVal82 & "," & HVal83 & "," & HVal84 & "," & HVal85 & "," & HVal86 & "," & HVal87 & "," & HVal88 & "," & HVal89 & "," & HVal90 & "," & HVal91 & "," & HVal92 & "," & HVal93 & "," & HVal94 & "," & HVal95 & "," & HVal96 & "," & HVal97 & "," & HVal98 & "," & HVal99 & "," & HVal100 & "," & HVal101 & "," & HVal102 & "," & HVal103 & ") " & _
"Values(" & VVal1 & "," & VVal2 & "," & VVal3 & "," & VVal4 & "," & VVal5 & "," & VVal6 & "," & VVal7 & "," & VVal8 & "," & VVal9 & "," & VVal10 & "," & VVal11 & "," & VVal12 & "," & VVal13 & "," & VVal14 & "," & VVal15 & "," & VVal16 & "," & VVal17 & "," & VVal18 & "," & VVal19 & "," & VVal20 & "," & VVal21 & "," & VVal22 & "," & VVal23 & "," & VVal24 & "," & VVal25 & "," & VVal26 & "," & VVal27 & "," & VVal28 & "," & VVal29 & "," & VVal30 & "," & VVal31 & "," & VVal32 & "," & VVal33 & "," & VVal34 & "," & VVal35 & "," & VVal36 & "," & VVal37 & "," & VVal38 & "," & VVal39 & "," & VVal40 & "," & VVal41 & "," & VVal42 & "," & VVal43 & "," & VVal44 & "," & VVal45 & "," & VVal46 & "," & VVal47 & "," & VVal48 & "," & VVal49 & "," & VVal50 & "," & _
VVal51 & "," & VVal52 & "," & VVal53 & "," & VVal54 & "," & VVal55 & "," & VVal56 & "," & VVal57 & "," & VVal58 & "," & VVal59 & "," & VVal60 & "," & VVal61 & "," & VVal62 & "," & VVal63 & "," & VVal64 & "," & VVal65 & "," & VVal66 & "," & VVal67 & "," & VVal68 & "," & VVal69 & "," & VVal70 & "," & VVal71 & "," & VVal72 & "," & VVal73 & "," & VVal74 & "," & VVal75 & "," & VVal76 & "," & VVal77 & "," & VVal78 & "," & VVal79 & "," & VVal80 & "," & VVal81 & "," & VVal82 & "," & VVal83 & "," & VVal84 & "," & VVal85 & "," & VVal86 & "," & VVal87 & "," & VVal88 & "," & VVal89 & "," & VVal90 & "," & VVal91 & "," & VVal92 & "," & VVal93 & "," & VVal94 & "," & VVal95 & "," & VVal96 & "," & VVal97 & "," & VVal98 & "," & VVal99 & "," & VVal100 & "," & VVal101 & "," & VVal102 & "," & VVal103 & ") """
```

HVal values are simple cell.value references. VVal values are the same, the idea is that HVals get set, then a loop gets kicked off, assign VVals, update SQL, fire it through the update engine, repeat until the file is fully imported.

Here is where I am stuck. If I run the compile for the SQL statement, print the resulting string to a cell, ie:

```
Workbooks("Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Buttons").Cells(1, 1).Value = SQL
```

Manually copy that string from Workbooks("Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Buttons").Cells(1, 1).Value, and paste it directly into a 'SQL=""' statement, then run the update, it works.

If instead of printing the value to the cell, I just send the original SQL statement into the update module, I get a "An Object or Column Name is missing" error.

If I re-set SQL to equal the value of the cell the original SQL was printed into, ie:

```
Workbooks("Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Buttons").Cells(1, 1).Value  = SQL
SQL = Workbooks("Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Buttons").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

and send it to the update module, same "An Object or Column Name is missing" error.

The only time it is working is when I copy the string generated by the first chunk of code and printed to cell Workbooks("Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Buttons").Cells(1, 1).Value, paste it back into the VBA editor, close it off with quotations, and store it as "SQL=".

Does the ring any bells for anyone for why I get these error messages for 2 hands off methods of generating the "SQL" variable, but a seemingly straight forward manual step that isnt really changing anything gets things to work?

Comment: Yes, the "why use dynamic SQL" bell is ringing very loud. You should be using proper software that can do import/export, like SSIS. If you want to code it yourself, don't do it in VBA or you'll be in for a world of pain.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem in your "update module"

Comment: OK how about you give us the fully compiled query, there is clearly a bug in it. Looks like you are missing a bunch of single quotes

Comment: `"," & VVal103 & ") """` - why does your SQL string end with a single embedded double-quote?

Comment: @Tim Williams FTW. Such a dumb mistake, but that was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassingly lowest hanging fruit possible.

Last 3 characters of the dynamic SQL statement are '"""'. Get rid of the 2 erroneous double quotes and the statement getting stored in the variable doesn't end ')"'.

Copying it from the cell and pasting it back into the vb editor, I was adding 3 quotation marks to manually build the statement where I should have been needing to add 4.